# Pyjamas-desktop (pyjd) compiles, runs and quits

Tags: python, com, windows-8.1, mshtml, pyjamas

I'm running Pyjamas on Windows 8.1 with Python 2.7 (64-bit). I've struggled a bit with getting everything installed, but I believe the struggle has been fruitful -- I've run bootstrap, the file "run_bootstrap_first_then_pyjd_setup.py", and have moved on to experimenting with Pyjamas DESKTOP.

I'm trying to view the Hello.py example (in the examples/helloworld directory) by running both a run.bat file in the command line & by double-clicking in the GUI Windows Explorer. The code of the .bat file is below:

```
@echo off
python Hello.py
```

The program will compile, run, open up a white window then immediately quit. Which makes me think it's not quite running (or that Pyjamas doesn't interface with Windows 8.1). If I run the Hello.py file directly by typing

```
python Hello.py
```

into the command line, the same thing happens.

I'm guessing this is a Windows software versioning problem (8.1 isn't capable of running the current version of Pyjamas or .....any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't run into this particular error, but to help debug what is going on, you can try this:

```
python Hello.py
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo Failure Reason Given is %errorlevel%
   PAUSE
   exit /b %errorlevel%
)
```

If you can, get an IDE that can have a running console of python. Here is an [overly comprehensive list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python). Just quick browsing on the debugging column, I would say use Netbeans or PyDev with Eclipse.